# Заменить функцию strchr

Tags: c, функции

На что можно заменить strchr в коде? Чтобы было более примитивно, без функций. Буду благодарен, если поможете

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char str_in[30], * del;
    char zn[] = ".,:!?-;";
    int stats[7] = {0};
    fgets(str_in,sizeof(str_in),stdin);
    for(int i = 0; str_in[i]; i++)
    {
        if ((del = strchr(zn, str_in[i]))) // в этой строке заменить strchr(zn, str_in[i])
            stats[del-zn] += 1;
        if (str_in[i] == '.')
            break;
    }
    for(int i = 0; zn[i]; i++)
        printf("%c = %d\n", zn[i], stats[i]);
}
```

Comment: В смысле "на что заменить"? `strchr – поиск первого вхождения символа в строку`. Осталось самостоятельно реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

Ну все же предельно просто!

```
char * strchr(char * s, char c)
{
    if (s == NULL) return NULL;
    for(;*s;++s) if (*s == c) return s;
    return NULL;
}
```

Раз надо не просто разжевать, но и проглотить...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * this_is_not_strchr(char * s, char c)
{
    if (s == NULL) return NULL;
    for(;*s;++s) if (*s == c) return s;
    return NULL;
}
int main()
{
    char str_in[30], * del;
    char zn[] = ".,:!?-;";
    int stats[7] = {0};
    fgets(str_in,sizeof(str_in),stdin);
    for(int i = 0; str_in[i]; i++)
    {
        if ((del = this_is_not_strchr(zn, str_in[i]))) // в этой строке заменить strchr(zn, str_in[i])
            stats[del-zn] += 1;
        if (str_in[i] == '.')
            break;
    }
    for(int i = 0; zn[i]; i++)
        printf("%c = %d\n", zn[i], stats[i]);
}
```

Comment: Ммм.. не получается. Можете помочь, пожалуйста?)

Comment: Что помочь? Вставить код в текст? Вставил...

Comment: Как можно избежать использование функции strchr? Пытался по вашему, но ничего не получилось, поэтому прошу помочь

Comment: @Jack что вы подразумеваете под **функцией**?

Comment: Я привел полный код, как избежать использования стандартной функции `strchr`, заменив ее своей. Что вам непонятно-то? Ну замените в тексте все `strchr` на `this_is_not_strchr`... Вот так, как теперь в ответе - вас устраивает?

Comment: Как сделать то же самое, что и функция strchr, но без использования сторонних функций, а только самого алгоритма (т.е. цикла for). Попытался сделать так - `char* n = str_in; ... for(;*n;n++){ if(*n==*zn) stats[*n]+=1; }`, но ведь это не правильно

Comment: @Jack Так что в этом коде по вашему не так? `strchr` не используется. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю зачем, т.к. *товарищ Harry* ответил, но надеюсь, после этого, вы начнете разбираться в терминах:

```
    char str_in[30];
    char zn[] = ".,:!?-;";
    int stats[7] = { 0 };
    fgets(str_in, sizeof(str_in), stdin);

    for (int i = 0; str_in[i]; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; zn[j]; j++) {
            if (zn[j] == str_in[i]) {
                stats[j] += 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; zn[i]; i++)
        printf("%c = %d\n", zn[i], stats[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

По крайней мере в **gcc** внутри скобочного выражения можно писать код в блоке из фигурных скобок.

Вот так: `({ C code here })`

Результатом такой конструкции (аналогично результату, возвращаемого из функции) будет значение последнего выражения в  коде.

Таким образом вашу строку с `strchr()`

```
if ((del = strchr(zn, str_in[i]))) // в этой строке заменить strchr(zn, str_in[i])
```

можно заменить на следующий код без вызова `strchr()`

```
if ((del = ({char *p = zn; while (*p && *p != str_in[i]) p++; *p ? p : 0;})))
```

Зачем такая глазодробительная штука (*ну, кроме как прикрытая макросом* (в самом деле, внутри макросов этот стиль вполне уместен)) может на практике пригодиться -- ума не приложу....